# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod in Xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, xcode8

I am working with Cocoa pods. While I am installing the cocoaPods I am getting the problem like the

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
```

I tried so many commands which are mentioned in some time. I tried to update and also tried to install ruby even though It is getting error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. What is the mistake I am doing.

The error is coming like this

CG-iMac-Dev:siriSample imfuser$ pod install

````
Analyzing dependencies

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.2.0.beta.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
       Xcode : 8.1 (8B62)
         Git : git version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ a45ce117b1ea0dce36ed2a3e4d7d0b7f9db588a8
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.1.2
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks! 
target 'siriSample' do 

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0.2' 

end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:23:in `read_from_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:850:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:850:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:845:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:66:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:149:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:110:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=cannot+load+such+file+--+nanaimo&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6214 [open] [19 comments]
   14 hours ago

 - help!   cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6312 [closed] [5 comments]
   13 minutes ago

 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6281 [closed] [2 comments]
   3 weeks ago
````

Comment: Which command you are using?

Comment: sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: You try this : $ sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Try this **sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre** may be work

Comment: @YogendraGirase I tried that also but no use

Comment: @NileshFasate It worked If I give the command which you have given
But it is created only Pod file. It doesn't create any "WorkSpace".

Error:"LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo"  Something like this it is comming

Comment: @hrithib Can you please show your pod file and also run **sudo gem update --system** for updating your gem, let me know if it work or not

Comment: you go to this directory /usr/bin/   then delete pod folder and use sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: @NileshFasate I wrote the following code in my Pod file

platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'SiriExample' do
pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
end

Comment: @hrithib You have to write this like - **platform :ios, '8.0' use_frameworks! target 'SiriExample' do pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0.2' end**

Comment: @NileshFasate Even though not creating the "workspace". Eroor I am getting like this 

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6214 [open] [19 comments]
   14 hours ago

 - help!   cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6312 [closed] [5 comments]
   
 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6281 [closed] [2 comments]

Comment: @hrithib Please try with new project whether workspace create or not, simply without pod project adding.

Comment: @NileshFasate Yes WorkSpace is creating normally.

Comment: @hrithib Then may be I think problem is in pod project file like **Alamofire**

Comment: Not only for Alamofire for AFNetworking also it is coming the same issue

Answer (score 3):

This is a security feature in your system.

Try in a different path.

This worked for me to get rid of the problem. (in your terminal)

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with root permissions like sudo  might help.

Comment: can you elaborate the problem to check ?

Comment: I am trying to install the cocoaPods using the Command "sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods" but I am getting the above error which I have posted.

Comment: Again I uninstall the cocoaPods and trying to install but it is not working.